# PAM module for authentication by IP or other password-disabling module

Tags: pam

I'm looking for a Linux pam module that accepts any password for connections from a specific IP. I don't want to disable passwords completely.

I need it for migration from one imap server to another (cyrus to zimbra) without knowing every password. I used such a module some six years ago. That was for imap migration too. Unfortunately I cannot recall the name of the module and can't find it by other means either.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the pam_exec module -- this lets you run an external command, and if that command returns success then the module passes.  So you could pass it a small shell script do check the source IP address, and you are good to go.